# How can i add an index to my Azure Search Service using python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-search

Can someone provide me the python code to add an index in azure search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking under the `References` section on [`this page`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-azure-search), as of today there's no Python SDK available for creating an index in an Azure Search account.

You would need to consume REST API directly in your code. You can read the REST API documentation for creating an index here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-index.